# What records did Vinny gave sheriff to run the tests?

Tags: plot-explanation, my-cousin-vinny

In *My Cousin Vinny*, Vinny calls the local sheriff, ask to run records check & so he run the test at Vinny's request which leads to Billy & Stan release out of case. This is happened after when Vinny find some clue in Vito's **photos**.

What exactly records does Vinny asking sheriff to check?

Comment: From your other question: ["two men resembling Billy and Stan were arrested a few days earlier in Georgia for driving a stolen Pontiac Tempest, a car very similar in appearance and color to Billy's Buick Skylark, and in possession of a gun of the same caliber used to kill the clerk."](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73249/why-courtroom-not-aware-of-thugs-who-already-got-arrested)

Comment: Also: ["On a hunch, I took it upon myself to check out **if there was any information on a 1963 Pontiac tempest, stolen or abandoned recently**."](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0104952/quotes?item=qt0404595)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vinny knows that the tiremarks were made by either a car similar to Billy's Buick Skylark or a 1963 Pontiac Tempest, because he knows both have similar wheel bases, tire sizes, body types and independent suspension.  So he asks the sherriff if anyone had recently been arrested driving a 1963 Pontiac Tempest, and they did discover an arrest of a similar nature where the perpetrators were driving a Tempest.